# Hibernate insert table with OneToMany JoinColumn

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring, hibernate

I have two table: SubmitOrder and OrderItem
Table SubmitOrder contain @OneToMany(OrderItem) and @Join Column(submitOrder id).
Table OrderItem have a field contain SubmitOrder id.
The result only insert the data to submit_order table but not order_item table.

Not sure which part I mess up.

SubmitOrder Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="submit_order")
public class SubmitOrder {
    
    // Define Fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;
    
    @Column(name="pickup")
    private String pickup;
    
    @Column(name="subtotal")
    private double subtotal;
    
    @Column(name="tax")
    private double tax;
    
    @Column(name="total")
    private double total;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    private List<OrderItem> orderItem;
    
    public SubmitOrder() {}

    public SubmitOrder(String name, String email, String phone, String pickup, double subtotal, double tax, double total) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.pickup = pickup;
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
        this.tax = tax;
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPickup() {
        return pickup;
    }

    public void setPickup(String pickup) {
        this.pickup = pickup;
    }

    public double getSubtotal() {
        return subtotal;
    }

    public void setSubtotal(double subtotal) {
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
    }

    public double getTax() {
        return tax;
    }

    public void setTax(double tax) {
        this.tax = tax;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(double total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public List<OrderItem> getOrderItem() {
        return orderItem;
    }

    public void setOrderItem(List<OrderItem> orderItem) {
        this.orderItem = orderItem;
    }

}
```

OrderItem Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order_item")
public class OrderItem {

    // Define Fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="section")
    private String section;
    
    @Column(name="size")
    private String size;
    
    @Column(name="quantity")
    private int quantity;
    
    @Column(name="price")
    private double price;
        
    public OrderItem() {}

    public OrderItem(String name, String section, String size, int quantity, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.section = section;
        this.size = size;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

the data that pass from angular:

```
SubmitOrder {name: "Sam", email: "sam@email.com", phone: "221-442-3542", subTotal: 73.32, tax: 5.8656, …}
cartOrder: Array(8)
0: {id: 24, section: "Lo Mein", name: "Beef Lo Mein", size: "Small", price: 6.6, …}
1: {id: 29, section: "Dinner", name: "Peper steak with Onion", size: "Dinner", price: 8.46, …}
2: {id: 30, section: "Appetizers", name: "Vegetable Spring Roll (2 pc.)", size: "None", price: 2.42, …}
3: {id: 35, section: "Appetizers", name: "Vegetable Egg Roll (1 pc.)", size: "None", price: 1.32, …}
4: {id: 36, section: "Appetizers", name: "Roast Port Egg Roll (1 pc.)", size: "None", price: 1.32, …}
5: {id: 38, section: "Soup", name: "Wonton Soup", size: "Small", price: 2.42, …}
6: {id: 39, section: "Soup", name: "Egg Drop Soup", size: "Large", price: 3.2, …}
7: {id: 40, section: "Appetizers", name: "Chinese Donuts (10 pc.)", size: "None", price: 4.24, …}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
email: "sam@email.com"
name: "Sam"
phone: "221-442-3542"
pickup: "ASAP"
subTotal: 73.32
tax: 5.8656
total: 79.1856
__proto__: Object
```

REST Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class SubmitOrderRESTController {
    private SubmitOrderService submitOrderService;

    @Autowired
    public SubmitOrderRESTController(SubmitOrderService theSubmitOrderService) {
        submitOrderService = theSubmitOrderService;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/submit")
    public SubmitOrder saveOrder(@RequestBody SubmitOrder theSubmitOrder) {
        theSubmitOrder.setId(0);
        submitOrderService.save(theSubmitOrder);
        return theSubmitOrder;
    }
    
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public class SubmitOrderDAOImplement implements SubmitOrderDAO {
    // Define field for entitymanager
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public SubmitOrderDAOImplement(EntityManager theEntityManager){
        entityManager = theEntityManager;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void save(SubmitOrder theSubmitOrder) {
        // Get the current hibernate session
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        // Save rates
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theSubmitOrder);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you add more details about the problem? Do you have the controller and repository but not insert the OrderItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible problems is related to the name of the attributes that you send from Angular. In the entity, the list of "OrderItem" has the name "orderItem" but Angular sends with the name "cartOrder". Try to send the attributes in Angular with the same name as the attributes in the Entity.

Aldo, check if attribute "subtotal" was save in the table because there is a little detail. (Angular: "subTotal" vs Entity: "subtotal")

**Correct solution**

I did an API with your entity classes and I found the problem. The correct way to send the "orderItem" from Angular is without underscore (orderItem) and you need to not send the "id" in each element of "orderItem". I add the example of the API so you can download and try to insert with the example using Postman o some other tool. [API Example](https://gitlab.com/asacco-stackoverflow/question-hibernate)

Comment: thanks for point out the subtotal problem, I have fixed that. But there is another problem, the backend did not get the orderItems list `SubmitOrder [id=0, name=Yun, email=yun@email.com, phone=124-343-3433, pickup=ASAP, subtotal=73.32, tax=5.8656, total=79.1856, orderItem=null]
`

Comment: Did you change the name of the attribute in Angular, from "cartOrder" to "orderItem"?

Comment: yes, I did change the name of the attribute from 'cartOrder' to 'orderItem'

Comment: Just in case, because I don't have all the configuration of the API. Could you check if the problem persists changing "orderItem" to "order_item"? Because you can configure Spring Boot to translate the underscore to lowercase name.

Comment: try that but still come out null, I probably will try another way to save the data. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I did an API with your entity classes and I found the problem. The correct way to send the "orderItem" from Angular is without underscore (orderItem) and you need to not send the "id" in each element of "orderItem". I add the example of the API so you can download and try to insert with the example using Postman o some other tool.
[API Example](https://gitlab.com/asacco-stackoverflow/question-hibernate)

Comment: just use Postman to test it, its working ! Thank you very much for the help. Will refactor my front end code.

Comment: I modify the answer to add the repository. If everything is okay, please mark as correct the answer.